# Building a compiler steps

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-construction

I have been thinking about building my own compiler for a while and a few days ago I finally started on it. My compiler works like this:

- Parse code from my own file. (With a .exe file made with c++)
- Create assembly code
- Create a file containing those assembly code
- Compile that assembly file if it is made (done with a vbs script)
- Link the .obj file
- And we have our .exe file

Now I am having difficulties with finding the best way to parse my code. I haven't really made this yet but I will put my ideas here.

- Find all variables and declare them. variables will be preceded with a 'var ' (for now). uninitialized variables will be put in the .data? section and initialized ones in the .data section.
- Find the main procedure and start executing the functions and operations.

Now I was simply wondering if someone can improve my ideas. Or if someone has a better idea to make some kind of compiler and your own programming language.

Comment: This is far to broad a question for Stack Overflow.   Get a good book on compiler construction -- there are several.

Comment: This question is too big for an SO question.  To properly answer your questions would take a good book and/or a semester length course.  I took this online class and thought it was excellent:  https://www.coursera.org/course/compilers  (And yes, you build a compiler in that class, for an object oriented language no less.  Mine functioned 100% and even had some nice optimizations in it.)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a sounding board. Compilers are broad and complex topics, and when you have a specific question, come back and ask.

Comment: i dont know if its still relevant but search for "compilers - principal, techniques and tools"also called "dragon book"

Answer (score 5):

Get yourself a copy of [A. V. Aho, M. S. Lam, R. Sethi, J. D. Ullman: Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) and start studying

The book covers the necessary theoretical background, especially:

- Context-free grammars
- Recursive-descent, LL, LR parsing
- Symbol handling
- Intermediate representation